# range of $(I-\Delta)^{-1}$ on bounded domains

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth boundary. Let $A=\Delta$ laplace operator on $\mathcal{D}(A)=H^{2}(\Omega) \cap H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$.

Then in [Li, Xungjing, and Jiongmin Yong. Optimal control theory for infinite dimensional systems. 1995] says $(I-A)^{-1}: L^{2}(\Omega) \rightarrow \mathcal{D}(A)$ exists as an operator on $L^2$.

It' not clear to me why the range of $(I-A)^{-1}$ is $D(A)$, can someone explain or give some references?

Comment: The domain of $I-A$ is $D(A)$....

Comment: I haven't properly looked into it but I would guess this is related to [Hille-Yosida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hille–Yosida_theorem) ?

Comment: Yeah @ArcticChar right, what a stupid question 

Comment: You have to prove that $(I-A)\mathcal{D}(A)=L^2(\Omega)$.